# PHP array output modification

Tags: php, soap

I have the following SOAP call and I'm trying to convert the output to a different format. I can't seem to get it working right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function __construct($coid, $env, $app_id, $product) 
{

    $url = APP_ROOT."dev/install/wsdl/my.wsdl";

    try {
        $soapclient = new SoapClient($url);
        //This overwrites the location at the bottom of the WSDL file
        $soapclient->__setLocation('http://exampleurl'); 
        $params = array('clientOid' => $coid);
        $response =$soapclient->getClientSetup($params);

        print_r($response);
        echo "--------";

        var_dump($array);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

My output look like this (Notice there also isn't a productUrl and I need this key to display)

```
[
    {
        clientSetup: {
            selectedProducts: {
                0: {
                    code: "1001",
                    description: "datapoint 1"
                },
                1: {
                    code: "1049",
                    description: "datapoint 2"
                },
                2: {
                    code: "1032",
                    description: "datapoint 3"
                },
                3: {
                    code: "1013",
                    description: "datapoint 4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
[
    {
        code: 1001,
        description: "datapoint 1",
        productUrl: "NO_URL"
    },
    {
        code: 1089,
        description: "datapoint2",
        productUrl: "http://example.com/"
    },
    {
        code: 2101,
        description: "datapoint2",
        productUrl: "NO_URL"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($response);`?

Answer (score 0):

After decoding `$response` to an array from your call, simply loop through that array to format the output you want.

```
public function __construct($coid, $env, $app_id, $product) 
{

    $url = APP_ROOT . "dev/install/wsdl/my.wsdl";

    try {
        $soapclient = new SoapClient($url);
        $soapclient->__setLocation('http://exampleurl'); 
        $params = ['clientOid' => $coid];
        $response = $soapclient->getClientSetup($params);

        $array = json_decode($response, true);
        $products = [];
        foreach($array[0]['clientSetup']['selectedProducts'] as $p) {
            $p['productUrl'] = $p['productUrl'] ?? 'NO_URL';

            $products[] = $p;
        }

        echo json_encode($products, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "code": "1001",
        "description": "datapoint 1",
        "productUrl": "NO_URL"
    },
    {
        "code": "1049",
        "description": "datapoint 2",
        "productUrl": "NO_URL"
    },
    {
        "code": "1032",
        "description": "datapoint 3",
        "productUrl": "NO_URL"
    },
    {
        "code": "1013",
        "description": "datapoint 4",
        "productUrl": "NO_URL"
    }
]
```